# Write signed byte array to a stream

Tags: c#

I want to write signed byte array `sbyte[]` to a stream. I know that `Stream.Write` accepts only unsigned byte[], so I could convert `sbyte[]` to `byte[]` prior to passing it to the stream. But I really need to send the data as `sbyte[]`. Is there some way to do it? I found `BinaryWriter.Write` but is this equivalent to `Stream.Write`?

Comment: simply **cast** sbyte to byte. It is the same bits anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the fact that the CLR allows you to convert between `byte[]` and `sbyte[]` "for free" even though C# doesn't:

```
sbyte[] data = ...;
byte[] equivalentData = (byte[]) (object) data;
// Then write equivalentData to the stream
```

Note that the cast to `object` is required first to "persuade" the C# compiler that the cast to `byte[]` *might* work. (The C# language believes that the two array types are completely incompatible.)

That way you don't need to create a copy of all the data - you're still passing the same reference to `Stream.Write`, it's just a matter of changing the "reference type".

Comment: Why not `byte[] e = (byte[])data`?

Comment: @DrKoch: Because it wouldn't compile. I've added an extra paragraph to explain that.

Comment: thank you. but is 'equivalentData' going to be signed?

Comment: @Ivan: I don't know what you mean by that. It's a reference with a compile-time type of `byte[]`. Its execution time value is a reference to the same array as `data`, representing the same *bits* in different ways. For example, if you say `equivalentData[0] = 255;` then `data[0]` will be -1...

Comment: I specifically need to send signed bits, because they are going to be received on client side which is written in Java, and streamreader in Java accepts only signed bits. So this is why I was wondering if bits in equivalentData are signed or unsigned. If they are unsigned, then everything on client side must be converted after received

Comment: @Ivan: If you think of signed bytes as merely an interpretation of the underlying (unsigned) bytes, it will make sense. In the same way that 4 bytes can be interpreted as an integer, or as a float, or something else encoded as 4 bytes; you can interpret a single byte as a signed byte by interpreting the bits in the byte differently. You can not send "signed bytes", you always send (unsigned) bytes.

Comment: @Ivan: "I specifically need to send signed bits" makes no sense. Bits are just bits. Suppose you have a file with a single byte in, and that byte has bits "11111111". What's the value of that? 255 or -1? It depends on how you interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

Some Background:

An unsigned Byte has 8 Bits and can represent values between 0 and 255.

A **signed** Byte is the same 8 Bits but interpreted differently: the leftmost Bit (MSB) is considered a "sign" Bit with 0 meaning positive, 1 meaning negative. The remaining 7 Bites may represent a value between 0 and 127.

Combined a unsigned Byte may represent a value between -128 and +127

If you send such a byte over the wire (the network) it is up to the receiver to **interpret** it correctly.